# How to customize Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth to use a certificate but not have IIS Validate it

Tags: ssl, iis, owin

Hopefully I'm asking the question properly.

I have the following use case.  I have an application I want to run on https, and have the user pass an x509.  However, I want to forward that authentication off to an external LDAP and not have IIS authenticate/check the certificate.

If I go into IIS and set to Accept/Require I get a 403 error.  If I don't require then I never get prompted for the certificate.

My start-up class looks like the following

```
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {

            app.UseClientCertificateAuthentication(new DefaultClientCertificateValidator());
        }
    }
}
```

I then I have

```
    public class DefaultClientCertificateValidator : IClientCertificateValidator
    {
        public ClientCertificateValidationResult Validate(X509Certificate2 certificate)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Attempting to validate cert {certificate.SubjectName}");
            // For now just return true
            ClientCertificateValidationResult res = new ClientCertificateValidationResult(true);
            return res;
        }
    }
```

If I do not pass in a certificate it goes down the path of throwing an error because it couldn't find a certificate.   However, if I try to send in a certificate I get the server error of

> 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
> You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you
> supplied.

Is there something in IIS I need to do to basically say "Grab the certificate, forward it along but do NOT authenticate it?"

Comment: I don't think that's possible for IIS (or any other web server). Mutual SSL handshake requires the client certificate to be present, so the first web component talking to the browser (IIS in your case) must asks for and validate client certificates. Details can be found in articles like https://support.alertlogic.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002999732-How-does-SSL-mutual-authentication-work- and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the answer is a bit "Weird".  For IIS you need to do the following

```
netsh http show sslcert
```

This gets you your ssl certificate

Then copy this information off, you'll need it later.

Then do the following

```
netsh http delete sslcert ipport=YOUR_HOST:YOUR_PORT
```

then run the following

```
http add sslcert ipport=YOUR_PORT:YOUR_HOST certhash=[FROM THE FILE EARLIER] appid={[FROM THE FILE EARLIER]} certstorename=MY verifyclientcertrevocation=enable VerifyRevocationWithCachedClientCertOnly=disable UsageCheck=Enable clientcertnegotiation=enable
```

By flipping that bit to enabled, it allows to validate the X509 downstream